# Iterate two files, compare matching strings in rows, merge matching rows

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have two files with a list of organisms. The first file contains a list indicating 'Family Genus', so two columns. The second file contains 'Genus species', also two columns. Both files coincide in having the Genus of all the listed species. I want to merge both lists using each file's Genus to be able to add the Family name to the 'Genus species'. Thus, the output should contain 'Family Genus species'. Since there is a space between each name, I am using that space to split into columns. So far this is the code I have:

```
with open('FAMILY_GENUS.TXT') as f1, open('GENUS_SPECIES.TXT') as f2:
    for line1 in f1:
        line1 = line1.strip()
        c1 = line1.split(' ')
        print(line1, end=' ')
        for line2 in f2:
            line2 = line2.strip()
            c2 = line2.split(' ')
            if line1[1] == line2[0]:
                print(line2[1], end=' ')
        print()
```

The resulting output is composed of only two lines, and not the entire record. What am I missing?

And also, how can I save it to a file instead of just printing on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alternative solution.

```
f1 = open('fg','r')
f2 = open('gs','r')
genera= {}
for i in f1.readlines():
    family,genus = i.strip().split(" ")
    genera[genus] = family

for i in f2.readlines():
    genus,species = i.strip().split(" ")
    print(genera[genus], genus,species)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would process the files first and get a mapping of genus to to family and to the multiple species it may contain.  Then use that mapping to match them up and print them out.

```
genuses = {}

# Map all genuses to a family
with open('FAMILY_GENUS.TXT') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        family, genus = line.strip().split()
        genuses.setdefault(genus, {})['family'] = family

# Map all species to a genus
with open('GENUS_SPECIES.TXT') as f2:
    for line in f2:
        genus, species = line.strip().split()
        genuses.setdefault(genus, {}).setdefault('species', []).append(species)

# Go through each genus and create a specie string for
# each specie it contains.
species_strings = []
for genus, d in genuses.items():
    family = d.get('family')
    species = d.get('species')
    if family and species:
        for specie in species:
            s = '{0} {1} {2}'.format(family, genus, specie)
            species_strings.append(s)

# Sort the strings to make the output pretty and print them out.
species_strings.sort()
for s in species_strings:
    print s
```